# how to password protect the digitally signed pdf using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, digital-signature, pfx

I m creating and signing pdf using c#,itextsharp.Now i m using this code for password protection and digital sign.First i am protecting with password.Than i am signing.

the transmitted pdf is not asking password while opening?
Can someone tellme why is this happening?

Thanks..

```
string passprotectedfile = filename;

using (Stream input = new FileStream(signedfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                                     FileShare.Read))
{
    using (Stream output = new FileStream(passprotectedfile, FileMode.Create, 
                                          FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
        PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, regno.ToString(), "",
                             PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
    }
}
```

Code i am using for digitally sign.

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename,pass);
        Stream output = new FileStream(signedfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, output, '\0');

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(455, 105, 555, 170);
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(rect, 1, "sign");
        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, new PdfName("adobe.pkcs7.detached"));
        PrivateKeySignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256");
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, true);
        return filename;
```

then i am transmitting.

```
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=tes2.pdf");
            Response.TransmitFile(signedfile);
            Response.Flush();

            File.Delete(signedfile);
            File.Delete(newfile);
            File.Delete(passprotectedfile);
```

Comment: So what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: the transmitted pdf is not asking password for opening the pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `PdfReader` instance using an owner password that allows iText to decrypt the password protected PDF. That explains why the password protection is gone: you told iText to decrypt the file.

If you want a file that is signed as well as encrypted, you need to do both operations in one go, not sequentially! The `PdfStamper` class has different methods that allow you to set the encryption. Use one of these methods on the `stamper` object.